# How to get a signal from 74595

Tags: embedded, stm32

[image]

I used the code as shift`_register_write_byte(0xFF);`
I want to use the shift_register_write_byte function to generate an LED output based on an 8bit data variable.
But I did not receive a signal. How can I get a signal? Thank you!

```
  void shift_register_reset(void){
  GPIOA->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_9;
  Delay_us(5);
  GPIOA->BRR=GPIO_PIN_9;
  Delay_us(5);
  GPIOA->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_9;}

  void shift_register_clk_pulse(void){
      GPIOA->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_8;
      Delay_us(5);
      GPIOA->BRR=GPIO_PIN_8;
  }

  void shift_register_load_pulse(void){
       GPIOA->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_10;
       Delay_us(5);
       GPIOA->BRR=GPIO_PIN_10;
  }

  void shift_register_write_byte(uint8_t data){
    shift_register_reset();
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){

        if(((data>>i) &0x01) == 0 ){
            GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_15;
            HAL_Delay(5);
            shift_register_clk_pulse();
        }
        else if(((data>>i)& 0x01) == 1){
            GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_15;
            HAL_Delay(5);
            GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_15;
            shift_register_clk_pulse();
        }
    }
    HAL_Delay(5);
    shift_register_clk_pulse();
    HAL_Delay(5);
    shift_register_load_pulse();}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"I did not receive a signal. How can I get a signal?"_?

Comment: Have you tried values other then 0xFF? 0xC1 (11000001b) is a better test value.  It will verify the bit order on the LEDs and whether the LEDs are illuminated high or low (which it is not possible to determine from your "diagram").  You generate 9 clock pulses when you only need 8 - you will lose a bit (which also won't show up using 0xFF).  The 5 ms delays are unnecessary - you have more than adequate delays in the pulse functions.  If a bit is not zero, it can only be 1, so you need not explicitly test for 1 in the `else-if`, and for 1 why do you set then reset the pin?

Comment: Have you correctly initialised the GPIO pins as outputs and enabled the appropriate GPIO clock in the RCC?  All GPIO default to input, so we must take it on trust that you have initialised the I/O as required.

Comment: You can move `shift_register_clk_pulse();` to after the if/else since it is common to both.

Comment: Could also be a circuit design issue the "LED" box in the image tells us nothing.  And do you have your LEDs the right way around?